# Css class not getting removed in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I have the following code for Gridview:

```
<SelectedRowStyle CssClass="SelectedRowStyle" />
```

where I change the selected row to yellow color.

And then on a button click I want to remove the css class. I tried to handle that in code by following:

```
Gridview1.SelectedRow.CssClass=
Gridview1.SelectedRow.CssClass.Replace("SelectedRowStyle","")

Gridview1.SelectedRowStyle.CssClass=
Gridview1.SelectedRowStyle.CssClass.Replace("SelectedRowStyle","");

Gridview1.SelectedRow.Attributes.Remove("SelectedRowStyle");
```

But nothing works. Where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply assign empty string to CssClass proeprty and Remember you will need to rebind the grid view to get change

```
Gridview1.SelectedRow.CssClass = "";
```

Comment: I did bind the grid view. But the above code also doesnt work.