# Update not working in web page

Tags: c#, asp.net

There is web site where user login. I navigate to user info page where the information are displayed by retrieving the info from db based on the username. username is unique. I display all info in text box like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con);
SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
sdr.Read();
txtFirstName.Text = sdr[0].ToString();
txtLastName.Text = sdr[1].ToString();
txtAge.Text = sdr[3].ToString();
txtUserName.Text = sdr[4].ToString();
```

Then when allow users to modify changes in the same text boxes and allow them to update.

```
string query = "UPDATE users SET FirstName=@firstName,LastName=@lastName,Age=@age,UserName=@userName WHERE UserName='"+userName+"'";

con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", txtFirstName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", txtLastName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", txtAge.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", txtUserName.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But the value which the user changes are not being sent to db. I have done similar code before and it has worked. But now it fails to update. Where am I going wrong.

Comment: When you debug this, where does it fail?  Does the code for the query even run at all?  Is there an error from the database or from the code anywhere?  Is the query constructed with the values you expect at runtime?  How have you verified this?  We can't test this for you, you need to provide some runtime debugging information.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624811/different-ways-of-passing-sqlcommand-parameters). This question can help you

Comment: Try replacing that Username in the Where Clause with another parameter -maybe @OriginalUserName... That may or may not fix the issue, but it'll resolve the fact that you've got a potential SQL Injection issue.

Comment: Say I changed the age and debugged. When I move my cursor to  

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", txtAge.Text); 

it still has the old value

Comment: Where or how are you assigning a value to `userName`?

Comment: @Partha: `txtAge.Text` still has the old value?  Where is that being set?  It sounds like you might be over-writing your control values in `Page_Load`.

Comment: string userName = (string)(Session["user"]);

From login page

Comment: @Partha, your code only gets a new value when the user (or their browser) sends the data back to your code. Is there a button on the page corresponding to your code that submits or posts a request back to the same page or to another page with the code in your second code block?

Comment: In the 1st piece of code, I populate the text boxes. That function is called during page load

Comment: @Partha: Let's hope nobody ever gives their user the wrong name... http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: I validate those stuffs in login page. 
@KennyEvitt did not get you.

Comment: Your comment about how you "changed the age and debugged." leads me to believe that maybe the "new values" aren't being sent, or retrieved to the relevant page.

Comment: @KennyEvitt: I enable all the textboxes on a button click and user can update his info. Say he updates his age. Then I ask him for his password. Then on another button click I validate password and update db. The update code is 2nd piece of code, but the new value is not getting into the code.

Comment: @Partha: You *might* "validate those stuffs in login page" but that doesn't change the fact that *this* page has a SQL Injection vulnerability.  You're already using parameterized queries, just add another parameter for that value to fix the vulnerability.

Comment: How are the new values being passed to the code that validates the password and how is that code in return passing on the new values to the code that actually updates the DB? If you can, you should post an extremely simplified version of your code somewhere; unless the answer you accepted in fact resolves your problem. If so, consider that it's highly unlikely that someone else will find this question if they also are having the same problem you did, i.e. forgetting to check `IsPostBack`. Please consider editing your question to better expose the problem; or delete it.

Comment: @KennyEvitt The answer i accepted did solve my problem. I will make sure I post proper code from next time. Sorry for that.

Comment: I am not sure if I am allowed to ask this here. This is one more question I posted, can you please take a look at [this]
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23098720/css-class-not-getting-removed-in-code-behind)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments you say that this happens during `Page_Load`:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con);
SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
sdr.Read();
txtFirstName.Text = sdr[0].ToString();
txtLastName.Text = sdr[1].ToString();
txtAge.Text = sdr[3].ToString();
txtUserName.Text = sdr[4].ToString();
```

In the [ASP.NET Page Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) `Page_Load` gets called every time the page object instantiates, on every request.  So even if you're clicking a button and not initially requesting the page, that button results in a request to that page on the server, so `Page_Load` runs *before* the click handler for the button on that request.

So what's happening is:

- You request the page
- `Page_Load` inserts the current values into the controls
- You change the values on the page
- You click a button
- `Page_Load` inserts the current values into the controls
- You update the database with the values in the controls

See the second-to-last line?  Include a breakpoint in `Page_Load` when you debug this.  You're *overwriting* the values before you save them.

You can fix this by wrapping your initialization code in a check to `IsPostBack`:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con);
    SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    sdr.Read();
    txtFirstName.Text = sdr[0].ToString();
    txtLastName.Text = sdr[1].ToString();
    txtAge.Text = sdr[3].ToString();
    txtUserName.Text = sdr[4].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @David. I used to put populating of ddl's and grids generally in postback check, but missed this. Thanks a lot